# Print name instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to replace the values in the output with the names, but I have no idea on how to do it. For example `(cheese, eggs)` instead of `(1, 5)`.
I am starting to learn python, and some of the answers on other related topics I just don't understand.

```
def printPairs(arr, n, sum):     

for i in range(0, n):    
    for j in range(i + 1, n):    
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] <= sum):    
                print("(", arr[i],", ", arr[j],")", sep="")    

cheese = 1  
eggs = 5  
banana = 7  
apple = -1  
bread = 5 

arr = [1, 5, 7, -1, 5]      
n = len(arr)  
sum = 10      
printPairs(arr, n, sum)
```

output:

```
(1, 5)  
(1, 7)  
(1, -1)  
(1, 5)  
(5, -1)  
(5, 5)  
(7, -1)  
(-1, 5)
```

Comment: Uh, Use a `dict`?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thank you, I didnt know i have to accept the answer. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `dict`:

```
dict_ = { 1 : 'cheese',
          5 : 'eggs',
          7 : 'banana',
         -1 : 'apple',
          6 : 'bread'
          }    

def printPairs(arr, n, sum):
   for i in range(0, n):
       for j in range(i + 1, n):
           if (arr[i] + arr[j] <= sum):
               print("(", dict_[arr[i]],", ", dict_[arr[j]],")", sep="")

arr = [1, 5, 7, -1, 6]
n = len(arr)
sum = 10
printPairs(arr, n, sum)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
(cheese, bread)
(cheese, banana)
(cheese, apple)
(cheese, bread)
(bread, apple)
(bread, bread)
(banana, apple)
(apple, bread)
```

Comment: I think the key value must be unique against the value, but you are declaring two `5` keys in dictionary `dict_`

Comment: Thanks @DirtyBit . But If you change the dictionary key then you also need to change the `arr` value because ultimately `arr` value is used as key.

Answer (score 1):

May I recomend using a dictionary:

```
pairs = { 1: 'cheese', 5: 'eggs' ...}  # for all the values
```

Then change the print line to

```
 print("(", pairs[arr[i]],", ", pairs[arr[j]],")", sep="")
```

Comment: it works, the only problem is that the number 5 if defined twice. but the numbers were in this case just examples. thank you!